# Which article is correct? "I'm looking for a/the pair of shoes"

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

What article should I use when going into a shop and telling the manager I want to buy something?

> I'm looking for a pair of shoes

or

> I'm looking for the pair of shoes (I choose what I want to buy)

Some English language textbooks say: the article The is used for a choice

Comment: You must have misunderstood what "some English language textbooks" mean. Native speakers would *never* use the definite article in your context. We only normally use ***the*** when the *specific* referent is known to both speaker and audience, but in your context neither you nor the sales manager [yet] know *which* pair of shoes you will eventually "find" (and presumably buy).

Comment: It's **a situation**.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that when you're choosing something specific, you use "the" rather than "a". But in the case when you're walking into a shoe store, you're not yet ready to choose your shoes.

You'll probably look at dozens of different styles, maybe try 4 or 5 of them on, and *then* choose **the** red Adidas. Walking into the store, you knew you were going to buy **a** pair of shoes (just one pair among many pairs available), but it wasn't until the end that you actually chose **the** pair.

Comment: The only situation where I could see "the" being used is something like "I'm looking for *the* pair of shoes I saw last week" with a description of what they looked like, for example. But again, those are a *specific* pair of shoes you are looking for, and you know which ones they are already when you mention them.

Answer (score 0):

Correct: I'm looking for **a** pair of shoes.

We can use 'the' when the speaker and the listener know what pair of shoes is being referred to.)

I'm looking for the pair of shoes I saw a few minutes ago/yesterday.